# Show divs based on dropdown - Script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show div's based on dropdown selection using the following script. 
It works perfectly on a simple page without any thing in it; but when I put it in the page that I'm developing, it messes up the entire page, making it black and at the end of the URL I get this ...../myPage.html#someIdInThePage .

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function showTheTab(name) {
            name = '#' + name;
            $('div').not(name).hide();
            $(name).show();
        }

        $('#dropdown').change(function () {
            showTheTab($(this).val());
        });

        showTheTab($('#dropdown').val());

    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <p>
        <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
            <option value="Pubs" selected="selected">Pubs</option>
            <option value="Councils">Councils</option>
            <option value="Property">Property</option>
            <option value="Various">Various</option>
            <option value="Universitys">Universitys</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
<div id="Pubs">pubs</div>
<div id="Councils">councils</div>
<div id="Property">property</div>
<div id="Various">various</div>
<div id="Universitys">universitys</div>
```

Comment: its works good for me.Can u post the entire code??

Comment: try to change your function name to something else!!! Might work

Comment: working for me too  http://jsfiddle.net/kanishka_bandara/nZ8n4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `$('div').not(name).hide();` will hide every div on your page apart from the selected div. You're going to need a more specific selector to do the hiding

Example

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function showTheTab( name ) 
    {
        name = '#' + name;

        $('div.Tabs > div').not(name).hide();

        $(name).show();
    }

    $('#dropdown').change( function() {

        showTheTab( $( this ).val() );
    });

    showTheTab( $('#dropdown').val() );

});
```

Html:

```
<form>
      <p>
      <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
          <option value="Pubs" selected="selected">Pubs </option>
          <option value="Councils">Councils </option>
          <option value="Property">Property </option>
          <option value="Various">Various </option>
          <option value="Universitys">Universitys </option>
      </select>
      </p>
 </form>

<div class="Tabs">
    <div id="Pubs">pubs</div>
    <div id="Councils">councils</div>
    <div id="Property">property</div>
    <div id="Various">various</div>
    <div id="Universitys">universitys</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now the page is loading but all the dives are being shown! :(

Comment: the selector must be wrong for your code, can you post your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ ? Here's an example on there: http://jsfiddle.net/v4BYA/

Comment: it works but when i put a div in any of the divs, they'll be hidden!

Comment: change the selector to: $('div.Tabs > div').not(name).hide();

Comment: what you suggested here was perfect and is working great.
Now I want to use the same for a list as bellow: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dR6E5/

Could you help me out with the JS please?! Tnx

Comment: As usual, perfect! But may I ask why you changed  --- showTheTab($('#dropdown').val());  ---  in the last line to ---  showTheTab("1"); --- ?

Comment: That sets the first tab to be shown, #dropdown does not have a value so i just set it to the class name of the first tab

Comment: Thank you very much! I truly appreciate your kindness :)